# XCode, place breakpoints by by code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

i have a macro for checking and handling errors

```
#define ERROR_IF_ARG(x, y, z, w)\
    if (x) {\
        printf("\nERROR! {\n\tText : " y "\n\tExpression : (" #x ")\n\tIn file : %s\n\tLine : %d\n\tFunction : %s\n}\n\n", z, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);\
        w;\
    }
```

in code i call

```
ERROR_IF_ARG(!isOfType(UNI_STRING), "expected 'std::string', found '%s' ", UNITYPE2STR(type), return NULL);
```

sadly i cannot place breakpoints inside this macro, but is there maybe some way with using #pragma or __ to place a breakpoint mark by code? or else generate and interuption, **so i can trace the problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you're running in a debugger if you're looking to use breakpoints; how about using an assert within the macro?

Comment: +1, although he should just use the assertions instead of that macro.